# Install VSCode on jetsonNX

Tags: computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano, jetson-xavier

I want to install the latest arm version of VSCode on jetsonNX with jetpack5.1, but after installation, VSCode cannot run and no response.

I checked the system-monitor and there are VSCode components running.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to run code with no-sandbox flag with XavierNX:

```
code --no-sandbox
```